# How do I copy a file to local machine while logged in to remote ssh server

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, server, scp

I have a process (which I have put into an alias in .bash_profile) to get a log file from my remote ssh server, save it to my local machine and then empty the remote file.

At the moment, my process has these two commands:

```
scp admin@remote.co.za:public/proj/current/log/exceptions.log "exceptions $(date +"%d %b %Y").log"
```

to download the file to my local machine, and then

```
ssh admin@remote.co.za "> /public/proj/current/log/exceptions.log"
```

to clear the remote file. Doing it this way means that I'm logging in via ssh **twice**. I want this to be effecient as possible, so I want a way to only login once, do both operations, and then logout.

So if I can find a way to send the file to my local machine from the command-line of the server, I can do this:

```
ssh admin@remote.co.za "[GET FILE]; > /public/proj/current/log/exceptions.log"
```

Is there a way to do this? And if not, is there any other way to do achieve my goal while logging in once only?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh admin@remote.co.za "cat /public/proj/current/log/exceptions.log &&
  > /public/proj/current/log/exceptions.log" > "exceptions $(date +"%d %b %Y").log"
```

This works by catting the entire file to stdout which will flow through as the stdout of `ssh`, then truncating the file remotely (assuming `cat` succeeded).